# is it possible to drag and drop html elemnts in dreamviwer cs6

Tags: html, cordova, dreamweaver

I am developing a phonegap application using dreamviewr cs6. I use dreamviewr after a long time. In a previous version, I can rember that there was a html bar so that I could drag and drop html contents and design a site. but In dream viewer cs6 I couldnt find such a facility. Is there any special configuration to get html list to drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window->insert ctr+F2` is the key